# Remove app from play store

Tags: google-play

I've uploaded an app in play store and later I unpublished that. Anyhow, if the users who already installed and used the app. Even if the user uninstall the app, that time also he is able to see the app in play store using the app play store link. Is there any possibilities to delete the app completely from Play store?

My wish is, I don't want to see the app anymore in play store even for the existing users

Answer (score 46):

**TL;DR**: Open the Play Console. Select an app. Select `Release > Setup > Advanced settings`. On the `App Availability` tab, select `Unpublish`.

[image: Setup - Advanced settings]
[image: Unpublish app dialog]
[image: Verify app unpublished]

From https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9859350?hl=en&ref_topic=9872026:

> When you unpublish an app, existing users can still use your app and
> receive app updates. Your app won’t be available for new users to find
> and download on Google Play.
>
> #### Prerequisites
>
> - You have accepted the latest Developer Distribution Agreement.
> - Your app has no errors that need to be addressed, such as failing to fill in the content rating questionnaire or provide details about your app's target audience and content.
> - Managed publishing is not active for the app you want to unpublish.
>
> #### To unpublish your app:
>
> Open the Play Console. Select an app. Select `Release > Setup > Advanced settings`. On the `App Availability` tab, select `Unpublish`.

#### How to Disable `Managed publishing`

[image: Managed publishing overview]
[image: Managed publishing toggle dialog]

Comment: I unpublished already. But it is still showing for the existing users.

Comment: When you unpublish an app, existing users can still use your app and receive app updates. Your app won’t be available for new users to find and download on Google Play.
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113476?hl=en

Comment: Another way:-  you can change the visible name of the application (what you see and others will see in the store) by going to the "translations" tab of the application and changing the name in the "What's the name of your app?" field. The change should propagate immediately.

Comment: Can we able to remove the developer account? Will the app still available even if the developer account is deleted?

Comment: I don't think so it will help but you can give it a try after change your app name.

Comment: Update for 2019: Step 3 should now be: `Store Presence -> Pricing and Distribution`

Comment: We desperately need an update for this answer--the new UI is even MORE confusing than the old one!  Arrrrgh!!!

Comment: The google play store cannot and will not reach out to end devices and uninstall an app. This is by design. Once an app is on a device. There is no way to remove it, without the end user explicitly uninstalling it.

Answer (score 4):

You can't remove apps for users which already have it, they always retain the right to get the app back. This is to protect users if they damage their phone and want to restore it back to a previous state.

Out of interest, why do you want to stop this?

Comment: Due to the developer account name. Our client want it to be a separate brand instead of the existing company name

Comment: In that case, one option would be to create a new developer account and transfer the app between the accounts.

Comment: Your ID is good and we also looked for the same. But the problem was, we had the company name in the app package name itself so that we are facing issue

Answer (score 1):

Please check this [url](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9023647), now you can send a request to delete your app from play store.

> Delete an app or game
>   You can permanently remove draft apps or games from your Play Console. You can also delete:
>   Published apps or games that haven't been installed on any devices 
>   Published apps or games that no users are entitled to re-install

Answer (score 1):

Today, I used Google Play Support Chat to remove the apps from the console.
Follow this link https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/gethelp

In chat, you can give package names you want to have removed.

Comment: I just contacted Google support chat, and they said deleting apps is not possible. How did you achieve that?